# Bluetooth [0cf3:3004] turns off immediately

Tags: bluetooth, atheros, firmware

As soon as I enable bluetooth from the gnome settings, it turns back off.

```
[ 4241.696392] perf samples too long (2518 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 4306.801973] usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 4311.900179] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3004
[ 4311.900184] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4311.900186] usb 2-1.4: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[ 4311.900188] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[ 4311.900189] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
[ 4320.440868] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

What could be going on here? What commands shoul I try in order to find out?

---

```
$ dmesg | grep -i firmware; uname -a
[    1.509651] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x350f00)
Linux laptop 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 10:50:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
$ dmesg | grep ath3k
[   23.459930] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

Comment: Please edit to add results for `dmesg | grep -i firmware; uname -a`

Comment: @Jeremy31, ready. I was surprised that `sudo lshw | grep bluetooth` returned nothing. And yes, I am trying to use a bluetooth mouse, that works on the Windows7 on the same laptop.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? And please also add output of `dmesg | grep ath3k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the firmware installed for this adapter.

You can install it this way. Run in terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Comment: Hi, the source isn't there anymore, I have the same problem as OP, could you provide the current firmware? I'm on mint btw.